# Sub navigation to be as long as longest sub item

Tags: css

I am having trouble with my navigation menu.  Here is my CSS:

```
ul.main {
        background-color: #CCC;
        display: inline-block;
}

ul.main > li {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;

}

ul.subNav {
        background-color: #333;
        color: #FFF;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
}

ul.subNav li {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
}
```

What I am trying to do is make my sub navigation as wide as the longest sub item in the menu so the `ul.subNav` are as wide as the longest `li`.  I can't seem to make this happen.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This will need a jsfiddle please. OT: a good practice is to rename `.main` as `.mainNav` (I prefer `.nav-main` and `.nav-sub` but whatever) and then you can remove the element `ul` from your selectors. No need to know if it's an ul or a div or anything, the class is sufficient by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'll need `white-space: nowrap` on your subNav `li` elements:

```
ul.subNav li {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jWsHg/). If you want to know more, here are some links about the property:

- [W3 Wiki page on white-space](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space)
- [MDN page on white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space) (light-weight page)
- [W3 spec on white-space](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop)

Comment: Yes, this seems to do what I want.  I am not familiar with this attribute though.

Comment: Fair enough, I've added links to pages that explain the property in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen is right, and he beat me to it. `white-space: nowrap;` will do the trick. Here's 2 working demos I made to demonstrate:

[with nowrap](http://jsfiddle.net/mk3Q9/)

[without nowrap](http://jsfiddle.net/3SMwE/)